# Option append not adding values to select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, coffeescript

I am trying to add options to a dynamic select input, dependant on the value selected in another select dropdown.

I have managed to populate a data object upon selection of a value in the parent . All my triggers are also executed and the child select is disabled and should contain all the values from the data object, but it is not populated with any options.

JS (Coffeescript) code segment:

```
$ ->
  $("select[data-option-dependent=true]").each (i) ->
    observer_dom_id = $(this).attr("id")
    observed_dom_id = $(this).data("option-observed")
    url_mask = $(this).data("option-url")
    key_method = $(this).data("option-key-method")
    value_method = $(this).data("option-value-method")
    # prompt = if $(this).has("option[value=]").size() then $(this).find("option[value=]") else $("<option value=\"\">").text("Select a value")
    prompt = $("<option value=\"\">").text("Select a value")
    regexp = /:[0-9a-zA-Z_]+:/g
    observer = $("select#" + observer_dom_id)
    observed = $("#" + observed_dom_id)

    observer.attr "disabled", true  if not observer.val() and observed.size() > 1

    observed.on "change", ->
      observer.empty().append prompt

    if observed.val()
      url = url_mask.replace(regexp, observed.val())

      $.getJSON url, (data) ->
        $.each data, (i, object) ->
          observer.append $("<option>").attr("value", object[key_method]).text(object[value_method])
          observer.attr "disabled", false
```

The last section is of specific importance, as this is where the JSON data object should be converted into new options. Here is the object responded with in one case (As per Firebug):

```
{"rule_attributes":[{"id":25,"human_name":"Gender"},{"id":26,"human_name":"Age"}]}
```

In this case the child dropdown should have been appended with the Gender and Age options, but nothing has been appended.

**UPDATE 1**

If I substitute this line:

```
observer.append $("<option>").attr("value", object[key_method]).text(object[value_method])
```

....with a test:

```
observer.append $("<option>New Option</option>")
```

The New Option value is added. Something that I have noticed is that it gets added only once, even if I have two options in my each object. Is it perhaps an issue with the JSON object's structure?

**UPDATE 2**
Some extensive logging provides the following details in console:

```
console.log(object)
->  [Object { id=25, human_name="Gender"}, Object { id=26, human_name="Age"}]
console.log(key_method)
-> id
console.log(value_method)
-> human_name
console.log(object[key_method])
-> undefined
console.log(object[value_method])
-> undefined
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
console.log(data)
-> Object { rule_attributes=[2]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Put some text in the option

Comment: @Musa , I have added an update. I believe that this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @muistooshort , I have updated the indentation of my Coffeescript file.

Comment: Ur JSON looks valid. Did u check the values of `key_method` & `value_method` ? do they match with the properties in the response, ideally it should be `id` &  `human_name` in that order . Can you confirm on that ? Also do u see any error in the console ?

Comment: @Arkantos , I think you might be onto something. When I output "console.log(object[key_method])" & "console.log(object[value_method])" to my console log, I get an undefined value. Could you perhaps think of a reason for this?

Comment: when you say `object[key_method]` is undefined, it means that the property that ur looking in `object` doesn't exist, trying logging `key_word`, you'll know the reason

Comment: @Arkantos , I am not sure that I understand why it is not populating by looking at the logs. I have updated my question with all of the relevant log details. Not sure why it is not picking up the values in my object.

Comment: i get it now, the problem is in ur `data` object that you're passing to $.each. As you can see in your logs, `console.log(object)` prints an `array` object and that has 2 objects with keys id & human_name. The array object doesn't know anything of id/human_name, thats y you're getting undefined. Change what you're passing to your $.each. If not add the output of `console.log(data)` and i can tell u what to pass :)

Comment: @Arkantos , I have added the output of "console.log(data)" to my question. Little bit of a js newbie her :-). Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: just invoke `$.each data.rule_attributes`, now it will work :)

Comment: Haha.. i was in your place a year ago.. same issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change $.each invocation in getJSON callback from

```
$.each data, (i, object) ->
```

to

```
$.each data.rule_attributes, (i, object) ->
```

Comment: Just a small typo. data should become data.rule_attributes and not only rule_attributes.